# The position of "nicht"

Tags: negation

I have recently come across the following sentence:

> Warum dürfen wir den Apfelkuchen nicht essen?

I was wondering if placing "nicht" before "den Apfelkuchen" is correct:

> Warum dürfen wir nicht den Apfelkuchen essen?

Can anyone tell me why or why this is (in)correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are correct but can mean a different thing. Rule of thumb: the *nicht* is placed in front of the thing negated, which also gets the focus because of that:

> Warum **dürfen** wir den Apfelkuchen **nicht essen**? – Weil er noch heiß ist.
>
> Warum dürfen wir **nicht den Apfelkuchen** essen? – Weil ihr erstmal euer Gemüse essen sollt.
>
> Warum dürfen **nicht wir** den Apfelkuchen essen? – Weil der für Omas Kaffeekränzchen ist.

These examples are a bit constructed because the question already asks for the right thing, but I think you get the difference in meaning.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the answers to Q2 and Q3 are also valid to Q1. And the answer to Q1 and Q3 are also valid to Q2. — That being said, as an answer for beginners your simplication is fair enough.